# How can I install a certificate on a remote machine with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, certificate, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to install a certificate using PowerShell.  I'm testing the installation by creating a remote session with my own computer.  I know the command is correct because outside of the remote session it successfully installs the certificate.  When I do a remote session to my own computer I receive the error:

> Access is denied. 0x80070005 (WIN32: 5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED). This may be the result of user credentials being required on the remote machine. See
>   Enable-WSManCredSSP Cmdlet help on how to enable and use CredSSP for delegation with PowerShell remoting.

If I run this command without a remote session it works:

```
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath "\\network\storage\site.com.pfx" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\\LocalMachine\\WebHosting" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "foobar" -AsPlainText -Force)
```

When I execute the command (via `Invoke-Command`) with a remote session I get the error mentioned above:

```
$session = New-PSSession $Env:ComputerName
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath "\\network\storage\site.com.pfx" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\\LocalMachine\\WebHosting" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "foobar" -AsPlainText -Force) }
```

How do I work around this permission issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are experiencing a so called double-hop authentication issue. If using normal authentication you will not be able to authenticate to a second computer from the machine you are invoking the command on.

To solve this you can use CredSSP.

To enable CredSSP on the machine that is being called:

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server -force
```

To enable CredSSP on the client:

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer server.domain.com -force
```

The `-delegateComputer` parameter expects a FQDN but also takes wildcards.

After enabling CredSSP you can use it to invoke your command with the parameter `-authentication CredSSP`

Comment: As an addition to this answer, if you want to know how and why this works, check out the "Secrets of Powershell remoting" here: https://devopscollective.gitbooks.io/secrets-of-powershell-remoting/content/manuscript/accessing-remote-computers.html, Especially the last two sections.

Comment: Thanks for the response Paul.  I assume I can't run that enable command via a remote session (chicken and egg problem I presume)?  We're looking for complete automation of our server and application setup so I might have to approach this differently via a Group Policy or some other means.

Comment: @JustinHelgerson not 100% sure but i think you are assuming correctly ;) Group Policy is the way to go it seems: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204773(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had the darnist time trying to get around the permissions issue and finally went at it a different direction. There is a flaw\bug when it comes to modifying the permissions. Can't remember all the details but the ACL properties trys to access the ownership of the keys your trying to change. This may not be ideal for everyone but it worked for deploying a certificate to all our systems for NLA RDP.

```
Set-Location "c:\windows\system32"
#if certificate is missing, will install wild card certificate into the store
icacls 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys' /save C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys\ACLfile_for_Keys_Dir /T
takeown /f C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys\*.*
icacls 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys\*.*' /grant 'Network Service:(R)'
#icacls C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto /restore  C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys\ACLfile_for_Keys_Dir #(restores original ACL for recovery)
icacls 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\keys' /setowner system
icacls 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\keys\*.*' /setowner system
```

The two lines commented out was my backout plan in case something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first post, so take it easy on me. Apparently this question is still being asked, because my boss said, "Hey powershell nerd, can you *install a certificate or group of certificates on remote workstation(s)*?"

First and foremost, the best way to do this is through group policy (see reference doc; SECTION 'To distribute the list of trusted certificates by using Group Policy').

However, you won't be able to update the SST the GPO is pulling from without manually updating the SST yourself and then having your GP administrator reuploading it to the policy. This is important because new certs, expired certs, and revoked certs happen all the time and Microsoft is infallible and always keeps their CTL up-to-date.

To import certificates via Powershell to a single, remote Workstation:

#This allows you to tell a remote workstation to run a command from another workstation or server

Invoke-Command -ComputerName HOSTNAME -ScriptBlock{

#This is your working directory

cd C:\temp

#This will pull certs from Microsoft's CTL and wrap them into an SST

Certutil -GenerateSSTFromWU -f TrustedCerts.sst

#This will create a variable that access' the content/certs of the SST

$sstStore = Get-Childitem .\TrustedCerts.sst

#Foreachofthosecerts | Import the certificates into the Trusted Root CA

$sststore | Import-Certificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root

}

Reference Documents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn265983(v=ws.11)#redirect-the-microsoft-automatic-update-url-for-a-disconnected-environment

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/import-certificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps